# GOOGLE SHEET FORMULA spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

is there a way, if I want to highlight the cell if the date is current week, past week and next week ?

Comment: Use conditional formatting.

Comment: yup, but what is the formula :)

Comment: To get help, post few of your sample data and show your desired result, so that we can help you by providing correct formula.

Comment: for example:  the date today is aug 29, 2022, this week's dates are August 29 through September 3.

and presuming that these dates are entered in column n: (and rest of n). I want the cells to automatically become red if the date's are current week

also turn orange if the inputted date is the previous week and blue next. what the formulas would be. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't include your [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I created one to demonstrate.

> Select the date range, in this case `A2:A1000` and Go to Format > and then [Conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). Under format rules choose: Custom formula is, And paste this formulas for each rule.

| Rules | Formulas |
| --- | --- |
| Prev week | `=AND(A2>WORKDAY(TODAY()-14, 7)-7,A2<WORKDAY(TODAY()-14, 7))` |
| This week | `=AND(A2>WORKDAY(TODAY()-14, 7),A2<=WORKDAY(TODAY()-14, 7)+6)` |
| Next week | `=AND(A2>WORKDAY(TODAY()-14, 7)+7,A2<WORKDAY(TODAY()-14, 7)+14)` |

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

see `WEEKNUM()`:

[image]

---

try:

past

```
=(WEEKNUM(A1, 2)<WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2))*(A1<>"")
```

present

```
=(WEEKNUM(A1, 2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2))*(A1<>"")
```

future

```
=(WEEKNUM(A1, 2)>WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2))*(A1<>"")
```

---

to look only one week into past & future you can do:

past

```
=(WEEKNUM(A1, 2)<WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2))*(WEEKNUM(A1, 2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2)-1)*(A1<>"")
```

future

```
=(WEEKNUM(A1, 2)>WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2))*(WEEKNUM(A1, 2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2)+1)*(A1<>"")
```

[image]